# HTML Forms tables and Input Fields

Tags: php, html, forms, design-patterns, vs-web-site-project

I am beginning to code web pages to be used for automating business processes.
I want to create a page where a user can assign product categories to each product in a list and save it back to the database.

Currently i have a simple PHP page that will get data from a sql table, display it in a html table and also populate each row with an input field.. I now want to take input from the user and when the form is submitted the data is written  back to the sql table.

The issue i have is that im unsure what should come first.. the HTML table or the Form or the PHP and then echo the table and form out..

can anyone suggest best practices or where i can find the best way to approach this kind of development?

Regards,
Craig

Comment: Just as a first step, make sure that the information you have is tabular. (It sounds like it is, just a good thing to determine first). Second, if you pull information from a database, and you want to update already existing information, the easiest and quickest method will be to create the table on the fly, looping through the results from the database. In the while-loop, you go through the information you want to put into the table-row, and depending on what you want to update, you provide inputs for those values, and/or add some inputs to add / update specific values.

Comment: Thanks junkie, so would i echo the table and the form out inside the PHP tag?

Comment: Correct. Best practise would be to use one PHP tag, and echo everything you want to show, instead of jumping back and forth using multiple PHP tags.

Comment: thanks again Junkie!